# UILabel background set to be the width of it's length?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

As the picture is showing i've put a backgroundcolor of my UILabel which is in a TableView. As it is now the width of the background is set to the width that i've choosen in the storyboard. But, i'd like to set the width of the background to be as long as the UILabel length. Now they all are the same.. Any suggestions for a smart solution?!

[image]

```
// Appereance of the cell
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
    TableCell *cell;
    long row = [indexPath row];

    //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.TitleLabel.text = [self.categoryList[row] categoryName];
    cell.TitleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.0 saturation:0.0 brightness:0.0 alpha:0.4];
    cell.TitleLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 18;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the background **is** the size of the `UILabel` as all it is the background of the label. You need to resize the label to fit its contents and then the background size will also change.

Something like this should work before you return the cell.

```
CGRect frame = cell.TitleLabel.frame;

// save center to recenter after changing width
CGPoint center = cell.TitleLabel.center;

// only change width
frame.size.width = [cell.TitleLabel sizeThatFits:frame.size].width;
cell.TitleLabel.frame = frame;
cell.TitleLabel.center = center;
```

Comment: The result of the background is right, but when i do this the height is getting to low. So it's making the cornerRadius go bananas. And also the text is no longer centered to the view. Any suggestions how i get the right height for cornerRadius 18 and making the label set to align centered? @Dima

Comment: @MartinBorstrand check my edited answer to fix this. I've edited it to maintain the center and height.

Comment: Thanks, great! Just had to change from cell.center = center; to cell.TitleLabel.center = center; And to get some space on each side of the label to the background i set .width +10; so no it's perfect! Thanks again, made my day! @Dima

Comment: @MartinBorstrand fixed the typo in my answer, thanks :) And no problem!